# Given my question has been closed, how can I get an answer after editing it?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits, specific-question, closed-questions

My question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034380/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-object-from-the-context-if-i-only-have-the-entitysetnam), has been closed. I have edited it, and hope I have done a better job in asking it now. An answer would still be useful. Should I try asking it again?

Comment: You question shouldn't be re-opened as is.  You're asking, "Is there a better way?"  That's inherently vague and not constructive.  You should ask a more concrete verifiable question.  At best it belongs on Code Review.

Comment: That's a bit unfair @Servy, the OP says that they have to manually edit the code each time. "A better way" is not having to do this.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I'm not saying it's not possible to fix the question, but the question should be edited to ask about that specifically, instead of just saying, "make it better".

Comment: @Servy Regarding "At best it belongs on Code Review"  is that a tag or a manner of speaking?

Comment: @kirsteng It's a site.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

No, you shouldn't ask it again. Bringing it up on meta or chat is the correct way to go; if people agree with you that it should be re-opened then it will be.

However, you should remember your experience for the future. *Always* post what you have tried. There are a number of excellent blog posts that are linked all over Stack Exchange, which I would highly recommend reading:

- [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)
- [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

and as you can see it's open again already!

Comment: Thats wonderful. I edited it 22 hours ago and was feeling quite rejected.

Comment: @kirsteng, someone needs to see it before it can be reopened; even then there's no guarantees. By putting it in chat or posting on meta you risk more downvotes but you equally can get upvotes and are more likely to have the question re-opened. One thing I would say is that you should be double checking your question multiple times to ensure that they're up to scratch. Especially something to show you have tried something. I can't blame people who originally closed the question for doing so and it's far easier if your question never gets closed in the first place.